# Browser take long request as bad request when opened in a new tab

Tags: java, grails, request

In my grails application i have used a link which redirects to a search table according to the filters applied from a form. In the application i have appended all the query parameter in a params map. When the link is clicked in the same page search page opens but when it is opened in a new tab blank page appears. This happened because the browser took that long query as a bad request. Now my question is, is there any way to prevent from being a bad request when opened in new tab?

Comment: It sounds like the query string (HTTP parameters) is too long. Can you post what the link query string looks like?

Comment: what i've found is, the request originally is a post request but when opened in a new tab, request goes as a get request, and get request doesn't supports that much characters. Is there any way i can make the request post type even while opening in a new tab. I hope i make it clear